# $connection object scope in wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress, mysqli, connection

I have a hybrid website that uses mainly wordpress and some php pages.  All of my php pages work great in terms of db queries, but my wordpress pages are losing reference to the $connection object right after the get_header() call.

Please see pictures below of what I mean.  I am showing how the connection is lost at the footer section for simplicity of the screenshot, but I can't use it anywhere on the page after get_header().

[image]

[image]

I am not redeclaring it myself or anything like that and checked to ensure this was not on the list of wordpress [Reserved Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms).

If I "rerequire" the connection.php file it fixes the issue, but I wan't to understand why it is lost.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to do my require to open and close connection in each separate wordpress file (header.php, sidebar.php, etc.).  Hopefully this helps others who may find this question.